# Is it possible to slide open/closed a navigation drawer in uiautomator

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-uiautomator

Has anyone been able to pull this off.  UiScrollable, swipeLeft and swipeRight do not appear to have any affect on it.  I am using a Nexus 5 emulator with the latest api.  Has anyone been able to pull it off?

Comment: Please take a look at the edited answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

### **TL;DR**: Use the content descriptions set in the [`ActionBarDrawerToggle` constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#ActionBarDrawerToggle(android.app.Activity,%20android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout,%20int,%20int))

---

1. When you set up your Navigation Drawer, set an `ActionBarDrawerToggle` with content descriptions for opening and closing.

```
// Open drawer content description for accessibility
private static final String CONTENT_DESCRIPTION_OPEN_DRAWER = "Open drawer";

// Close drawer content description for accessibility
private static final String CONTENT_DESCRIPTION_CLOSE_DRAWER = "Close drawer";

private void setUpNavigationDrawer() {
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, CONTENT_DESCRIPTION_OPEN_DRAWER, CONTENT_DESCRIPTION_CLOSE_DRAWER);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}
```

2. In your `UiAutomatorTestCase`, to open/close the drawer, find the UI object by the open/close content description defined in step 1 and perform a click on it.

```
// Open drawer content description for accessibility
private static final String CONTENT_DESCRIPTION_OPEN_DRAWER = "Open drawer";

// Close drawer content description for accessibility
private static final String CONTENT_DESCRIPTION_CLOSE_DRAWER = "Close drawer";

private void openNavDrawer() throws UiObjectNotFoundException {
    findViewByContentDescription(CONTENT_DESCRIPTION_OPEN_DRAWER).click();
}
private void closeNavDrawer() throws UiObjectNotFoundException {
    findViewByContentDescription(CONTENT_DESCRIPTION_CLOSE_DRAWER).click();
}
private UiObject findViewByContentDescription(String description) {
    return new UiObject(new UiSelector().description(description));
}
```

**Warning**: If you use the [Material design approach](http://www.google.co.uk/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) for the navigation drawer (where the drawer opens on top of the `Topbar` and behind the status bar), the "hamburger" icon will be drawn behind the drawer, making the `closeDrawer()` method not to work. As a workaround, you can just select the section that is open in the drawer menu; this closes the drawer and shows the same section that was there before opening it.

Comment: this is for clicking the door open....im looking to slide the door open with my uiautomator test.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
UiObject view = new UiObject(new UiSelector()."use what you want to identify the view");
Rect bounds = view.getBounds(); // Returns the bounds of the view as (left, top, right, bottom)
int center_x = bounds.centerX();
int center_y = bounds.centerY();
// Now you have the center of the view. You can just slide by using drag()
getUiDevice().drag(center_x, center_y, center_x + "amount of pixels", center_y)
// Where amount of pixels can be a variable set to a fraction of the screen width
```

I used this idea on a drawer that slides from left to right on a file browser app.
I did not use the exact same code as above because I'm using a python wrapper for uiautomator. (https://github.com/xiaocong/uiautomator)