# Open drawer with UIAutomator without modifying application code

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

I'm trying to run a UI test using UIAutomator on an application that exists outside of the project from which I am launching the test. Because I'm working with an application that is outside of my test project, I can't use Espresso with it (as far as I know). I want to open the left drawer on this application. Espresso had a very simple way of doing this

```
openDrawer(R.id.drawer_layout)
```

but it appears to be more complicated with UIAutomator.

Somebody asked a similar question elsewhere, and the recommendation given to them was that they should modify the drawer in the source code of the application they were testing so that UIAutomator could open it more simply. I don't have access to the source code of the application I want to test, though, so I unfortunately can't do that. It also seems like using general drag and swipe functions doesn't work so well either, but I'm not certain about that.

Is it possible to open a drawer using UIAutomator? If so, what's the best way?

Answer (score 1):

You must use the content description of the `ActionBarDrawerToggle`. If you look the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html), you will see that the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` just have two constructors which both have a `openDrawerContentDescRes` and `closeDrawerContentDescRes`. So without changing your code, you can use the answer from this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898852/is-it-possible-to-slide-open-closed-a-navigation-drawer-in-uiautomator).

Comment: I viewed that topic before posting my question, but I assumed that I would need to add ActionBarDrawerToggle inside of the source code of the application. Are you saying that it can be implemented inside of the test itself?

Comment: You do not have a ActionBarDrawerToggle ? I think you must have one, see [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#ActionBarIcon). If you do not have one, maybe you should provide a simple code, so I will try to help you

Comment: I do not have access to the source code of the application I'm trying to test, so I can't add one there or even look to see if there is one. I examined the application using uiautomatorviewer to see if I could possibly find the ActionBarDrawerToggle element but I didn't see one there. I have implemented a navigation drawer without using an ActionBarDrawerToggle before, I believe, so I'm not certain there is one.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you want to do is open the side drawer you can do it like the user would:

- Click the app button in the action bar

or

- Slide from left edge to the right (to the middle of the screen should be enough but I've found that sometimes it does not fully open it provoking an immediate closing. So I'd advise you to slide till the right edge, e.g.)

With the second option you don't even have to know the id of any element.